# Can extra fan noise be due to upgrade from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04?

Tags: sound, 20.04, fan

I have run my laptop with Ubuntu 19.10 for more than six months without trouble, but after the recent update to 20.04 the fan is on at max level almost all the time. I guess this may be due to some hardware that went defective, but am wondering if there's anything I can do at the OS level to harness it. The computer is so noisy I can't really use it any more. Below is system information collected with `inxi`. Also, noise happens all the time, even when `top` shows only about 1% CPU usage. I did install and start `tlp`.

```
System:    Kernel: 5.4.0-40-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.1 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa)
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Hewlett-Packard product: HP ENVY dv6 Notebook PC v: 088A120000305910000620100 serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: Hewlett-Packard model: 1819 v: 52.24 serial: <filter> UEFI: Insyde v: F.29 date: 10/03/2013 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 52.2 Wh condition: 57.0/57.0 Wh (100%) model: 13-24 MO06062 status: Discharging 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i7-3630QM bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Ivy Bridge rev: 9 L2 cache: 6144 KiB 
           flags: avx lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 38314 
           Speed: 1198 MHz min/max: 1200/2400 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1197 2: 1197 3: 1197 4: 1197 5: 1197 6: 1197 7: 1197 
           8: 1197 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2) v: 4.2 Mesa 20.0.8 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel 7 Series/C216 Family High Definition Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
           bus ID: 00:1b.0 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-40-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Ralink RT5390R 802.11bgn PCIe Wireless Network Adapter vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: rt2800pci v: 2.3.0 
           port: 4040 bus ID: 04:00.0 
           IF: wlo1 state: up mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: r8169 v: kernel 
           port: 2000 bus ID: 05:00.0 
           IF: eno1 state: down mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 698.64 GiB used: 43.03 GiB (6.2%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: HGST (Hitachi) model: HTS541075A9E680 size: 698.64 GiB 
RAID:      Hardware-1: Intel 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] driver: ahci v: 3.0 bus ID: 00:1f.2 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 686.18 GiB used: 21.11 GiB (3.1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 35.0 C mobo: 35.0 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 363 Uptime: 2d 16h 56m Memory: 7.67 GiB used: 2.39 GiB (31.2%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: 
           gcc: 9.3.0 Shell: bash v: 5.0.16 inxi: 3.0.38
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fan constantly running on hp elitebook 8460p ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166988/fan-constantly-running-on-hp-elitebook-8460p-ubuntu-18-04-3-lts)

Comment: Not sure I see how it does.

Comment: "The computer is so noisy I can't really use it anymore" does not really seem to be a software issue, and it costs you nothing to check whether this possibility is true or false.

Comment: I've seen a few posts just like this, most were related to nvidia drivers.  I don't see anything nvidia related in your output, is there supposed to be?  Sometimes it has both the default intel graphics and a larger GPU.

Comment: @rtaft No Nvidia card. I wish there was one so I had some hope there was something I could fix.

Comment: @karel I probably wasn't clear. I agree it costs me nothing, I'm just not sure how to use the information you provided. The temperature sensor output is always 35-45 C, as you see in my printout. What does `psensor` offer extra? Please clarify if possible, thanks!

Comment: I doubt its a hardware issue since it started with the OS update.  Anything in `/proc/acpi/`?  What is in `/etc/modules`?

Comment: @rtaft Nothing in `etc/modules`. In `/proc/acpi` there is a `wakeup` file and a `button` directory.

Comment: @Vox I looked your output and it says *Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A*. This is not a bad thing. It might simply mean that your laptop vendor installed its own fan on the CPU that the sensors program is unable to read the fan speed from. Changing the temperature and fan speed app maybe won't help because they all use the same sensors program. Without knowing the fan speed you're back to guessing why the fan is so noisy, and you're right, my link didn't help you with that. Do you think the fan would still be noisy if you ran an Ubuntu live session from a live USB?

Comment: @karel The fan is noisy even in a live session and noisy throughout the restart process from the live to the installed. I guess this indicates it's a hardware problem. Not sure replacing the fan will help though, since it may be the sensor. I wonder if one can replace the sensor(s). What is your take on this?

Comment: I'm a geek who over the years have replaced many noisy computer fans with a 100% success rate. I have never seen a computer with a defective temperature sensor. This may be partially due to the fact that I run a temperature app on all of my computers. A computer fan normally is attached by 4 small screws, one on each corner. I remove the noisy fan and take it to a computer store when shopping for its replacement.

Comment: @karel This is good to know, will install `psensor` anyway and also try to replace the fan.

Comment: I had the same issue after upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04. It was definitely software issue, since it was fixed by installing 20.04 from scratch (not via do-release-upgrade)