# CPU fan runs continuously

Tags: 20.04, power-management, fan, overheating

I have a Lenevo Ideapad 720S-13IKB (Type 81BV) with Ubuntu 20.04 in it. Note: [Support page](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/700-series/720s-13ikb-type-81bv?linkTrack=Caps%3ABody_BrowseProduct&searchType=0&keyWordSearch=).

Even when my computer is at idle and using less than 5% of processing power and less than 1GB ram my computers fan makes loud noise and it runs every time .

My idle CPU temperature resides in the range of 40C to 45C which is medium hot. The weird thing is that the fan runs at really at high speed even when RAM being used is less than 1 Gb and processing power being used is less than 5% and it is really annoying.

Hope i can get some help with this.

Comment: CPU fans are controlled by BIOS aka UEFI.

Comment: @Pilot6 Can you help me to change it?

Comment: To change what? Lenovo UEFI? Only they can do it.

Comment: @Pilot6 I am sorry.I am new to this .you don't have to be harsh.

Comment: Show me the output of `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: @heynnema 6MCN31WW

Comment: I forgot to ask for the EXACT model # 720s you have.

Comment: @heynnema 720S-13IKB

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fan constantly running on hp elitebook 8460p ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166988/fan-constantly-running-on-hp-elitebook-8460p-ubuntu-18-04-3-lts)

Comment: Your BIOS is up to date. Edit your question and show me `ps auxc | grep -i therm` and `free -h` and `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness`.

Comment: Also, look in your BIOS for a fan control setting.

Comment: Had the same problem. 18.04 -> no problems 20.04 -> fan constantly running. Machine is a Fujitsu E746...

Answer (score 4):

Initially my fans were running a lot too. But installing `tlp` worked really well for me. Fans rarely spin now and the system stays cool. Just follow:
`sudo apt install tlp` for Ubuntu. For other distributions and OS, follow [Official TLP documentation](https://linrunner.de/tlp/installation/index.html)

Just FYI, my system is a Dell Inspiron 15 7572 (running Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: TLP is to save battery not to correct fan speed which runs continuously on Ubuntu

Comment: Actually don't you think it's kind of inter-related? TLP helps in killing/slowing-down those processes which are not being actively used by the system which ultimately decreases the load on the CPU and hence slows the fan down @ACV

Comment: It happened every time when my notebook went to idle that the fan started to spin crazy. Even though I closed everything. For some reason `tlp` fixed the issue for me too.

Comment: That's exactly what I was talking about! @ZoltánSüle

Answer (score 3):

@CapTen101 I thought so because I am having the same problem on desktop PC. In Windows the fans are quiet, but in Ubuntu they constantly run on higher speeds for some reason. And there are no high loads in my case. So I thought that rather a bug / misconfiguration in fan speed rather than fans responding to high CPU load.

Comment: It's the opposite for me. Even when I do decent heavy tasks, my fan noise is not that much in Ubuntu, but as soon as switch to windows? My fans go crazy (Windows 10). Recently I upgraded to Windows 11 and only since then the situation is better